# selectionChange or ItemClick

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, listener, extjs4.1

I am designing an extjs application where I have couple of panels. and one of them of has a grid. I know I can either do selectionChange on the grid listener or itemClick.

Which one should I use? Or moreover which one is better. I obviously load data on the right panel once the grid item is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one get fired only when the selection changes (as you might has guessed) and give you a array of selected record (which might be just one) while the second one get called for each click and give you only the one record you clicked on.

For your case I would tend to use the second event and save the last last clicked record internally. I would then only load the second grid if it was not already loaded for this record.

Comment: I see... thank you so much for clearing this up sra... I definitely need itemclick... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

your grid is displayed as table on page at runtime so you can add onClick() event on grid or table cell during onrowdatabount event of grid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manoj. I am using Extjs, so I don't have an option on onrowdatabound event...  I know that's a great feature in .net framework